# django url in template correct way to add parameter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

in **views.py**

```
class LaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = IlSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ilfiltro = self.kwargs['miopar']
        return models.Pippo.objects.filter(pippo=ilfiltro)
```

in **url.py**

```
url(r'^pippo/(?P<miopar>.+)', views.LaViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="Serializzata"),
```

this is a working url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/pippo/1
```

but if I put in a template:

```
{% url '1' 'Serializzata' %};
```

or

```
{% url 'Serializzata'?1 %};
```

keep getting this error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '?1' from
>   ''Serializzata'?1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

> **url**
>
> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name)
>   matching a given view and optional parameters. Any special characters
>   in the resulting path will be encoded using iri_to_uri().
>
> This is a way to output links without violating the DRY principle by
>   having to hard-code URLs in your templates:
>
> `{% url 'some-url-name' v1 v2 %}`

So in your case:

```
{% url 'Serializzata' 1 %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'Serializzata' 1 %}">
```